# Problems when using Firebase Tools

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

I'm having troubles when I try to execute firebase commands in the Node.js console. Tipically, it shows me the next sentence (for example, when I execute firebase list):

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

I'm currently logged in.

When I try to deploy, it shows the next message:

> npm ERR! code EPIPE
>
> npm ERR! errno EPIPE
>
> npm ERR! syscall write
>
> npm ERR! EPIPE: broken pipe, write

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same IDENTICAL issue!

Node version: 10.16.0

npm version: 6.9.0

How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

try to reinstall `firebase-tools` with `npm install -g firebase-tools`

and make sure to either have a default `projectId` set or pass one with parameter `-P`.

it would be great, if you'd add more information; eg. the [firebase.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) (which might be at fault).

Comment: Finally, I could fix it, but I don't know how did I do that... Anyway, it's solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Kico Klaiber ... uh... PLEASE, don't you really have any idea of what you did to fix this error ? I'm desperate, totally stuck with my firebase deployment cause of this error. And no one out there seems to know hot to fix it, nor on stackoverflow, nor on github official firebase-tools page...